# Django TemplateView searching in wrong place

Tags: python, django, django-urls, urlconf

My Django structure is:

```
testing
    contacts
        __init__.py
        templates
            contacts
                index.html
        (additional modules)
    testing
        __init__.py
        templates
            testing
                test.html
        urls.py
        (additional modules)
```

---

Inside of the main URL module, `testing.urls`, I have a urlconf that is as follows:

```
url(r'^testing/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='testing/test.html'))
```

The problem is, it keeps looking in `contacts.templates.contacts` for the `test.html` file. With the existing urlcon, the debug page says the following:

Template-loader postmortem

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/testing/test.html (File does not exist)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/testing/test.html (File does not exist)
/Users/*/Developer/django/testing/contacts/templates/testing/test.html (File does not exist)
```

It always defaults to the..........................^^^^^^^^^^ `contacts` folder for some reason. Is there some other parameters for TemplateView or `template_name` that can control this? Any help appreciated!

---

*Update - Inside `settings.py`*

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: How do you define template dirs in settings.py?

Comment: @Mirac7 updated question with section of `settings.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `testing/testing` directory is not currently being searched by Django. The easiest fix is to add it to the `DIRS` setting:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testing', 'templates')],
```

Another option would be to add `testing` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Then Django would find your template, since you have `APP_DIRS=True`. However I wouldn't recommend this, because in your case `testing/testing` is the special directory that contains the `settings.py` and root url config.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the additional recommendation against putting `testing` app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. You recommend keeping the 'root' (`testing`) app out of there because it should only be used as a type of router to the correct app?

Comment: The directory containing `settings.py` and the root url conf isn't usually included in `INSTALLED_APPS`. As you say, the root url conf usually includes urls from other apps. I have seen some people include it in `INSTALLED_APPS` before, so I'm not saying you absolutely shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 3):

By specifying `"APP_DIRS": True`, you are telling django to search for template files inside each app installed. Check in `settings.py` whether all your apps are contained within `INSTALLED_APPS`. If they are, you can try to force django to look for the templates in your app.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'testing', 'templates')],
        ....
    },
]
```